# How to pass dates to getFullYear ()?

Tags: javascript

must accept the date of men. how to convert date using getFullYear?

My code
    const getMenCountByYear = (users) => {

```
    const men = users.filter((users) => users.gender == 'male');
    const years = users.map((users) => new Date(users.birthday));
    const yer = years.getFullYear();

    return dates = (acc, year) => {
    if(_.has(year, acc)){
      acc[year] =+ 1;
    } else{ 
      acc[year] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  };

  const userByYear = yer.reduce(dates, []);
  console.log(yer);
}

console.log(getMenCountByYear(users));
export default getMenCountByYear(users);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
function getMenCountByYear (users, gender = 'male') {
    return users.filter(user => user.gender === gender)
    .reduce((result, user) => {
        const year = new Date(user.birthday).getFullYear();
        return {...result, [year]: (result[year] || 0) + 1 };
    }, {});
}

getMenCountByYear(users);

//{1963: 1, 1973: 3, 1980: 2, 1999: 1, 2012: 1}

getMenCountByYear(users, 'female');

// {2012: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
    const yer = years.map((years)=>years.getFullYear());
```